# Is there any examples on how to export the final visualization as a static map or an animated video in kepler-gl?

Tags: data-visualization, kepler.gl

> Using kepler.gl, a user can drag and drop a CSV or GeoJSON file into
>   the browser, visualize it with different map layers, explore it by
>   filtering and aggregating it, and eventually export the final
>   visualization as a static map or an animated video.

It's [clearly](https://eng.uber.com/keplergl/) should be possible ([repo](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl) on Github).

Answer (score 0):

On the kepler.gl interface, there's a button to export static plots as images. As far as I can tell, there is no  option for video or gif export for animated videos. A screen recorder might be a workaround.

[kepler.gl image export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHe57.png)

Answer (score 0):

The feature to download animated video or GIF doesn't exist at the time of writing this answer. However, you may follow the below mentioned issues raised on [Kepler's Github repo](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl) where people have raised similar requests:

[Export to video](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/issues/104)

[Export to GIF](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/issues/195)